# Using the Firefox addon "Modify Headers" to change Referrer

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, proxy, firefox-extensions, http-referrer

Hey there, I want to quickly and easily change my referrer to test something...

In the past I know there was nifty little Proxy programs that allowed you to enter whatever you wanted as your **HTTP Referrer**, but now I understand it's easier just to use the "[Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967/eula/50889?src=addondetail)" Firefox extension... Except I don't know what to enter into the addon!

I can't find any documentation, and the "Open Help" button links to a (pretty much) empty page on Bugzilla!

Can anyone please help, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier and more convenient to use an extension specifically developed for that purpose, e.g. [RefControl](http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/).

Comment: Thanks, that was much easier! I'd still appreciate some documentation for "Modify Headers", but oh well.

Comment: Well, I don't have time to completely describe that extension, but try to select "Modify" in combobox, then type "Referer" in leftmost field and your desired referer address in the next one, and press Add. That should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

i use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/header-tool/ it's more friendly

you just need to enable it from the side panel menu (view>sidebar>headertool) and write inside

X-Forwarded-For : 10.0.0.2

you can get more info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old but here is the answer to your question:

1. Enable/start the addon
2. From the dropdown menu on the window you show select *modify*
3. In the 1st field write *Referer*
4. In the 2nd field write your desired referer
5. Click "add"

Now you should be able to see your new referer below, followed by a green light (indicating an active action.